# Can I submit an application started one year ago to the Ubuntu App Showdown?

Tags: application-development

I started developing an application one year ago. I published it in SourceForge and it runs in Ubuntu, but I did not send it to the Software Centre. May I send it to the Ubuntu App Showdown contest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are only allowed to submit applications that you started to work on the day or after the Ubuntu App Showdown started.

Rule 1.

> **Novelty**: all submissions must be new open source applications, created either as an individual (the Participant) or in a team. The application must contain exclusively original code and the Participant must be the original author of the content.

You can find the full list here [Showdown Rules](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/rules/)

Comment: I guess you are right. I am the creator of the application, but it has taken me almost an year to develop it.

Comment: there was also some one asking in the live stream last week, if they could work on some abandoned application they have worked on, but the answer to that was no.